# Get index of first row that matches with a pattern

Tags: linq, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a datagridview with some columns and rows. One of the columns is string type (`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`). I would like to iterate over all the rows of this `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to find the index (row index) of the first element that matches with a specific string so I do:

```
int rowIndex = this.dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .ToArray()
    .First(row => row.Cells[this.colDesired.Index].Value == stringToSearch)
    .Index;
```

but an error is raised.

I want to use Linq and lambdas.

Comment: It would help if you said what the error message is.

Comment: error message thrown is: System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Core.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works for me well. Few things to notice:

1. You don't have to do a `ToArray` on the IEnumberable `Cast`.
2. Ensure `this.colDesired.Index` has a valid value. Else it will raise runtime exception.
3. Default value of `DatagridViewCell.Value` will be null, hence you should get an appropriate formatted value (`DatagridViewCell.FormattedValue`), depending on the `FormatType` of your cell which here is text type, to handle null cases.
4. `DatagridViewCell.FormattedValue` is an object so you will have to convert it to a string first.

Do this:

```
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().First(row => row.Cells[this.colDesired.Index].FormattedValue.ToString() == stringToSearch).Index;
```

Comment: You are right, there was something wrong: stringToSearch was not being found in a special case. So, this is working now. No need to do a ToArray.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int rowIndex = this.dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
       .First(row => row.Cells[this.colDesired.Index].Value == stringToSearch).Index;
```

Comment: You can format your answer for it to look like code by adding backticks (`)  around it.